# How to Align Footer Text on the Right and on the Left of webpage?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to align text and its link on the left and on the right side of my footer of my webpage. The problem is that the text that i want to be on right side falls in left side means Both text is showing in left side. I want them to be even on the same line but one on left side and one on right side. 
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks for the help!

**Here are the codes-**

**CSS-**

```
#footer{
display: none;
width: 100%;
height: 28px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
padding: 13px 7px 0px 17px;
font-size: 13px;
color: #848484;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
border-top: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
}
.designedby{
        text-align: left;
}
.copyright{
       text-align: right;
}
```

**PHP/HTML-**

```
<div id="footer">Designed By
<class="designedby"><a href="http://www.techxyz.co">techXYZ.co</a>
<class="copyright"><a href="http://www.techxyz.co/techxyzmedia.html">copyright</a></div>
```

**Screenshot of Resulting Footer- **

[click to view footer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQMJT.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is because, when you use `text-align`, it aligns the text inside of that element to the left or right of that element. So if your text is say `10px` wide, and the element is `10px` wide, it'll still show up on the left side of the screen, even though you have `text-align` set to `right`. To fix this problem, simply add a

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

to your CSS for your `.copyright`.

```css
#footer{
//display: none;
width: 100%;
height: 28px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
padding: 13px 7px 0px 17px;
font-size: 13px;
color: #848484;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
border-top: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
}
.designedby{
        text-align: left;
}
.copyright{
       position: absolute;
       right:0;
       margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">Designed By
<span class="designedby"><a href="http://www.techxyz.co">techXYZ.co</a></span>
<span class="copyright"><a href="http://www.techxyz.co/techxyzmedia.html">copyright</a></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier thing to do is to just do the following:

```css
.container{
width: 100vw;
height: 28px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
font-size: 13px;
color: #848484;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
border-top: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
/*NEW*/
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="footer">Designed By
    <a class="designedby" href="http://www.techxyz.co">techXYZ.co</a>
  </div>
  <div class="copyright">
    <a href="http://www.techxyz.co/techxyzmedia.html">copyright</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

All you are doing is creating a container and use flexbox to align the child elements the way you want it.

`justify-content: space-between;` does the trick of separating both sections of the footer you have.

Comment: Do not forget to close this question by choosing the best answer. It helps so other people can focus on other questions as well.